# Upper bounds for two events of random variable following Poisson distribution

Tags: inequality, poisson-distribution

So $X$ follows Poisson with $L>0$ and $\operatorname{E}[X]=\operatorname{Var}(X)=L$. We are dealing with two events:
$A=\{X \leq L/2\}$ and $B=\{X \geq 2L\}$. I have calculated that $P(A) \leq 4/L$ and $P(B) \leq 1/L$ and I want to calculate the upper bound for $P(A \cup B)$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A\cap B=\left\{2L\le x\le {L\over 2}\right\}=\emptyset\\\to\\\Pr(A\cup B){=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)\\=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)\\\le {5\over L}}$$therefore $$\Pr(A\cup B)\le {5\over L}$$

Comment: That was indeed my answer which is the sum of P(A),P(B) : 1/L+4/L=5/L. However my teacher asks (since we are using Chebyshev's inequality) a better value i.e least upper bound if I understood correctly. Your thoughts please.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any better upper bound using Chebyshev's inequality. Of course the exact value can be found which I don't think to be the main purpose here :)

Comment: Please share it with me. I appreciate your assistance.